# ImportError: libLerc.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, import, structure, importerror, project-structure

[image: my Project-Structure]

Using this structure i try to import GRIBDownloader using `from modules.GRIBDownloader import GRIBDownloader` (in the GRIBDownloader file is a class called GRIBDownloader) with `weathertryouts.py` as my main file in which i try to import this.

I researched some other pages on how to structure modules and there are some people that do it the same way, but it just doesn't work for me, I always get the error `ImportError: libLerc.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Your problem is not with python import. You are trying to use something which internally uses libLerc.so. Can you show what you import in GRIBDownloader?

Comment: ```from datetime import date```
import os

import requests
```from time import time```
import xarray as xr
```import netCDF4 as nc```
from time import sleep

Comment: yeah you're right, when i delete the imports i can import it in my main, thanks a lot, now  i know at least where to look for the problem

Comment: you're welcome. If you want further help you can attach snippets of your import to the question